# Live javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to configure a live caluator based on the Input of a form field.
My problem is, that I simply can not figure out how I would display the result on the Website.

```
<label class="contactform-label" for="contactform-member"><span class="contact_form_span">Member*:</span> </label>
<input class="contactform-input" type="text" id="contactform-member" placeholder="Member" name="member" value="" />
<span id="member-kosten">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(ausgabe)</script>
</span>



var price = 90;
var member = document.getElementById("contactform-member").value;
var calculate = Math.sqrt(price * member);
var ausgabe = (calculate);
```

Comment: @RuchishParikh Normally these tags would not be shown in SO code samples. In fact, they are not necessary and best omitted.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696679/outputting-a-live-calculation-based-on-field-values-in-a-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```js
function fun(){
var price = 90;
var member = document.getElementById("contactform-member").value;
var calculate = Math.sqrt(price * member);
var ausgabe = (calculate);
document.getElementById("member-kosten").innerHTML = ausgabe;
  }
```

```html
<label class="contactform-label" for="contactform-member"><span class="contact_form_span">Member*:</span> </label>
<input class="contactform-input" type="text" id="contactform-member" placeholder="Member" name="member" value="" onkeyup="fun()" />
<span id="member-kosten">
    
</span>
```

Comment: The problem with this code as I see and experience is, that it wont acually show the result of the "member" that has been entered right on the start. What i mean is that after you enter "1" you will be left with the result of "0" after that the calculations really just start. After typing "2" you get the result of "90" which is the result of the previous Member entered.

Comment: can you please explain calculation.? Do you need to plus the value like if i enter 10 and let say result come 20 and then i change input from 10 to 15 then result will be 20 + 30 = 50 and 30 will get from 15 and prev is 20.

Comment: I need it to be instantly displayed. If i enter "1" i instanly need "90" to popup. Currently there seems to be a delay of one phase in entering the value. Currently it always calulates the last number that has been entered.

Comment: Thank you very much Rushish!

Answer (score 1):

Set the html of element `member-kosten` from the script (last line):

```js
var price = 90;
var member = document.getElementById("contactform-member").value;
var calculate = Math.sqrt(price * member);
document.getElementById("member-kosten").innerHTML = calculate;
```

```html
<label class="contactform-label" for="contactform-member"><span class="contact_form_span">Member*:</span> </label>
<input value="10" class="contactform-input" type="text" id="contactform-member" placeholder="Member" name="member" value="" />
<span id="member-kosten">
</span>
```

Comment: I have checked your fiddle but your code not seems like dynamic. I am changing value from input at same time result not change.

Comment: If possible, try to use a Snippet, like @Ruchish has done.  The snippets work pretty much like JSFiddle, but work inLine in SO.   Just click the < > tag.